# Overflow in to body using HTML and CSS?

Tags: css, html, background, web

I want the background image of one of my divs to overflow into the body section. I've tried overflow:visible without any luck.

Check the pic:

[image: wish it would overflow]

See how the gold bits get cut off on the edge of the div? Suggestions please?

Here's my set up:

in the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
```

in the CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #0e0a04;
}

#container{
        max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top:60px;
    background-color: #0e0a04; 
    background-image: url(/bundles/tabredirector/images/background-image.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position: -70px -20px;  /*x,y*/
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Thanks!

WHAT I ENDED UP IMPLEMENTING:

Thanks for all of your suggestions, they inspired my solution. My final solution was to use a master div (position:relative with z-index:-1) and my container (position:absolute z-index:1) and stick an image in the master div that can be positioned absolutely. This way the content always sits on top and the background isn't clipped.

Comment: code pls.. we dont know your structure

Comment: Using a background won't work, because the background doesn't overflow like the content would. You can't use an `img`?

Comment: added code to question, sorry

Answer (score 1):

first post your markup and css. Also give the div a width:100%.

Comment: I need the div to be 960px though

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure there is a div outside your containing div. You can have a container above and below it which will hold all your other content.

Then you need to have a 100% width div with the full bg image centered.

Then within that div add another div for your content which can be 960 wide with an auto left and right margin to center it to the page.

Paste your HTML in your post as well the css is not enough as you need to add to your html!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Background images on an element only appear within that element.

If you want your `<div>`’s background image to appear outside the boundaries of the `<div>`, you need to assign the background image to another element instead, e.g. the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#fullWidthImage {
    background-color: #0F9;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
#centeredContent {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #09C;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>top site content </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div><!--container-->

<div id="fullWidthImage">
<div id="centeredContent">
content bla bla
</div>
</div><!--fullwidthImage-->

<div class="container">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>bottom of site content </p>
</div>
<!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```